# Reading Data from UIWebView

Tags: iphone

How to read UIWebView Data.
i want to read View Source of the url in the UIWebView.
anybody has any idea then let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should do

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.apple.com"]];
```

However if you're determined to use the UIWebView to get the HTML, you can try

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

or

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```